# Display WiFi captive portal login page on Linux

Tags: linux, wifi

When I connect to a WiFi hotspot with a captive portal or HTML login interface, I find that I need to guess the portal's IP address, generally running through this list:

1. 192.168.0.1
2. 192.168.1.1
3. 10.0.0.1
4. 10.0.1.1
5. ... etc

It's guess-work, and tedious. Is there a tool for Linux that automatically detects and takes me to the correct address so I can enter my starbucks receipt's WiFi code?

Answer (score 2):

There may well be a smarter way to do this but if you have a list of the candidate IP addresses you could easily put together a python script that uses requests to try to get a web page from each in turn, *possibly looking for likely text in each*, and then use `webbrowser.open( )` to open your browser to the correct one.

Something like:

```
#! usr/bin python3

import sys
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib import error
import webbrowser

def try_ip(ip_address: str) -> bool:
    """ Try to get a web page from the IP address."""
    try:
        resp = urlopen(f"http://{ip_address}/", None, timeout=1)
    except error.URLError:
        return False
    resp.close()
    return resp.code == 200

IP_LIST = [
    "192.168.0.1", "192.168.1.1",
    # etc
   ]

def main():
   """ The main loop """
   for ip in IP_LIST:
      if try_ip(ip):
          webbrowser.open(f"http://{ip}/")
          sys.exit()

   sys.exit("None of the usual IPs worked")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```